# error: ‘SurfFeatureDetector’ is not a member of ‘cv’

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to work out how to use OpenCV on ROS.

I've gone through the cv_bridge tutorial and understand how to convert to the sensor_msgs::Image to the format used by OpenCV, in order to use the image with OpenCV libraries, and convert it back to sensor_msgs::Image. And by the cv::circle and cv::NamedWindow examples in the cv_bridge tutorial, I assumed that I can use the algorithms in the OpenCV documentation by referring to the cv namespace.

So I decided to write a simple program to try out the feature detector algorithms in OpenCV, referring to http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html. And got to this point:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "panda");

  cv::Mat image;

  image = cv::imread(argv[1], 0);

  int minHessian = 400;
  cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

  while(ros::ok())
  {
  cv::namedWindow( "Display window");

  cv::imshow( "Display window", image );
  cv::waitKey(3);
  }

  return 0;
```

}

But I got an error:

```
error: ‘SurfFeatureDetector’ is not a member of ‘cv’
```

It works with the cv::SurfFeatureDetector line commented out. I'm stuck at that point. I don't think I'm missing any headers. Any help?

Please and thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56268/error:-%E2%80%98surffeaturedetector%E2%80%99-is-not-a-member-of-%E2%80%98cv%E2%80%99/) by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oh, just found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968993/opencv-undefined-reference-surffeaturedetector-and-bruteforcematcher

```
"#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>"
```

---

Originally posted by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) with karma: 172 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2